# Printing out in Python

Tags: python, fileparsing

I'm writing a program in which a user enters sales in a text file, the program reads the file and prints out the total amount for each sales category. Here's an example of a text file:

```
Alice;Lodging;49.99;10/12/2016
Bob;Dining;8.42;10/13/2016
Charles;Lodging;55.76;10/14/2016
David;Dining;19.95;10/15/2016
Eve;Rental;105.99;10/16/2016
Frank;Rental;raft;10/17/2016
```

The program must have two exceptions: IOError for wrong file name and ValueError if the amount cannot be parsed into a float. For ValueError, the program must continue with that line being skipped.

Here's my code so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(float)
filename = str(input(("Sales file: ")))
  try:
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        _, key, val, _ = line.split(';')
        try:
            my_dict[key] += float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print ('The amount %s, cannot be converted to a float!', line.strip())
except IOError:
    print ("No such file or directory:", filename)
    sys.exit()
```

Every time I run it, I get this:

```
Sales file: sales.txt
The amount %s, cannot be converted to a float! Frank;Rental;raft;10/17/2016
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Look at what's in the third section of that line. There's no number there; it just says `raft`.

Comment: What's with the random "raft" in the text file?

Comment: Please fix your indentation also, your `try/except` block is messed up.

Comment: Douglas, that's where the ValueError exception comes to play, since you can't parse a string into a float at the moment.

Comment: string formating is done with a `%` sign, not a `,` - 
Ex: `"Hello %s!" % name`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to actually format the string. Try this:

```
print ('The amount %s, cannot be converted to a float!' % val, line.strip())
```

Note the `% val`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with you code. Actually the problem is there in your file. Your file contain incorrect format data for the third field in the last line. Thus, you're getting exception, when you try to convert string to float, because the value is not suitable for converting it to float.

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(float)
filename = str(input(("Sales file: ")))
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
        _, key, val, _ = line.split(';')
        try:
            my_dict[key] += float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print ('The amount %s, cannot be converted to a float!' % val, line.strip())
except IOError:
    print ("No such file or directory:", filename)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: The value raft was place there so the ValueError exception can show up. I have to still be able to calculate the total amounts of each category, even with "raft" being there.

Comment: I think you are able to do so. Try printing the value of my_dict and see, if you are getting values populated into it or not.

Comment: One more question, how can I print out the value of my_dict on separate lines. For ex: Lodging: \n Dining: \n Rental: \n?

Answer (score 0):

It feels dumb to answer this question, but "raft" in Frank;Rental;raft;10/17/2016", is what it causing your error.
If you are having a different problem that has something to do with this, please say so so we can answer it.  Why is "raft" there?